# Combine integer fields filter

Tags: views

My need is to combine fields which their data type is **integer**.

I did not find a module for that. Or is there? The "Global: Combined fields" filter supports strings only.

Which approach would you recommend to achieve this? Thanks!

[Edit]

After seeing a comment from @scronide I am adding here some info (this is more generic so I do not comment his comment).

One might indeed choose the direction of saving a value in another field. It may be indeed as a computed field, but also as another integer field which - in its turn - holds the wanted value using code or rules.

However, I wanted to consider the on-the-fly retrieving the items.

Still, may be the separate field direction is better to go with. I will give here my exact situation, also as @Roy Segall suggested.

GIVEN
 - Using Search API indexes for the view's exposed filter;
 - Multiple integer field in a few content types. In the "Person" content type I have: "Year born", "Was active from", "Was a king from", etc. In another content type "Work" I have "Year written", "Year published", etc.

NEED
- The exposed filter is in a view where both content types are located and should return results of any item of any content type which holds a value bigger than or equal to the search value in any of the integer fields.

NOTE
As I am not an expert regarding performance, I am not sure which direction is the way to go; that is, saving a separated field (shared one across types) and index it for a simple filtering, or rather indeed filter on the fly among multiple fields.

Thanks for using your calories in your brain to help me think...
Amir

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) to the content type to calculate the sum of the other fields–stored as an integer–and then you can use it as a Views filter. You will need to re-save your nodes to generate the computed field values.